# Sql server update multiple columns from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read lots of post about how to update multiple columns but still can't find right answer.

I have one table and I would like update this table from another table.

```
Update table1 
set (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)=(t2.a,t2.b,t2.c,t2.d,t2.e,t2.f,t2.g,t2.h,t2.i,t2.j,t2.k)
from 
(
  SELECT ..... with join ... where .... 

) t2
    where table1.id=table2.id
```

If I running only select statement (between brackets) then script return values but not working with update

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TSQL does not support [row-value constructor](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors). Use this instead:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET a = t2.a,
    b = t2.b,
    (...)
FROM 
(
SELECT ..... with join ... WHERE .... 
) t2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: how can we do the same in sqlalchemy

Comment: engine.execute(
        """UPDATE table1 
SET a = t2.a,
    b = t2.b,
    (...)
FROM 
(
SELECT ..... with join ... WHERE .... 
) t2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id""")

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to use a sub-query you can also simply do the following....

```
Update t1 
set t1.a  = t2.a
   ,t1.b  = t2.b
   ,t1.c  = t2.c
   ,t1.d  = t2.d
   .......
from table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE .......
```

Comment: In a recent (2014 I think) version of MS SQL Server, we tried this and it balked at the t1. designation on the target fields.  Once we removed them the update worked as expected.  We used Inner Join rather than just Join, so perhaps that makes a difference.  So, we used "set a = t2.a, etc.".

Answer (score 1):

The above solution will work only for MSSQL.
In case of MySql you just need to first declare the tables

```
UPDATE 
      table1 t1 ,table2 t2 
set 
      t1.field=t2.field 
where 
      t1.id=t2.id;
```

In my case this worked..!!

Answer (score 0):

The UPDATE  SET commands implicitly apply on the table specified by , and it is not possible to specify the table on the SET operation.

Edit: Specify only the column name you want to update, do not mention the table.

Comment: So can you explain what the OP should do?